# SQL Query for No Active Status

Tags: mysql, sql, database, status

**Scenario**: I have a table which has a status of active or deleted. Let's say we are talking about car owners. The status in the table can reflect the fact that there were 2 previous owners (i.e. - deleted status) and that there should be only 1 current owner which has an "active" status in the table.

**Question**: How would I write a query involving a table like this to only include results where there is no current owner (i.e. - no row for that car with an "active" status)?

The following will only match if there's at least 1 row which matches the condition stated above. It is therefore not valid for what I'm seeking:

## Test query 1

```
SELECT *
FROM car_owners
WHERE status = 'deleted'
```

## Test query 2

```
SELECT *
FROM car_owners
WHERE status != 'active'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
select co.*
from car_owners co
where not exists (select 1
                  from car_owners co2
                  where co2.car_id = co.car_id and co2.status = 'active'
                 );
```

If you just want the `car_id`s, you can use aggregation:

```
select co.car_id
from car_owners co
group by co.car_id
having not max( status = 'active' );
```

You can also phrase the `having` as:

```
having min(status) = 'deleted'
```

Comment: Typo again, shouldn't `having not max( status = 'active' );` be `having not max(status) = 'active';` ?

Comment: @cid . . . That might also work, but the intention is to treat `max()` as "boolean or".  It could also be:  `sum(status = 'active') = 0`, which is how I usually write the logic.

Comment: That's an interesting way to filter aggregated queries, `max()` would then result 0 or 1. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NOT IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator for this.

---

Table Structure and Sample data

```sql
CREATE table car (
  carid int, 
  ownerid int, 
  carstatus varchar(50)
);
INSERT INTO car 
VALUES 
  (1, 1, "active"), 
  (2, 3, "active"), 
  (3, 5, "active"), 
  (4, 11, "deleted"), 
  (4, 12, "deleted"), 
  (4, 23, "active"), 
  (5, 13, "deleted"), 
  (6, 35, "deleted"), 
  (6, 38, "deleted"), 
  (6, 53, "deleted"), 
  (6, 10, "active"), 
  (7, 13, "deleted"), 
  (8, 16, "deleted");
```

SQL Query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   car
WHERE  carid NOT IN (SELECT carid
                     FROM   car
                     WHERE  carstatus = "active")
```

Output

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| carid  | ownerid  | carstatus |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|     5  |      13  | deleted   |
|     7  |      13  | deleted   |
|     8  |      16  | deleted   |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Online Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0746c1/9/0